# Referencing GLFW's callback functions from a Class

Tags: function, class, opengl, glfw

So, I have this simple class, witch initializes GLFW and creates a window:

```
namespace ALT {

    struct InputInformation {
    GLfloat lastX;
    GLfloat lastY;
    bool keyboard[1024];
    };

    class Window {
    public:
        Window(GLuint width, GLuint height, std::string title);
        ~Window();

        int run();

    private:
        void setUp();
        void mainLoop();

        GLuint _width;
        GLuint _height;

        GLFWwindow* _window;
        std::vector<Shader> _shaders;

        std::unique_ptr<ALT::Heightmap> _heightmap;
        std::unique_ptr<Model>          _nanosuit;
        std::unique_ptr<ALT::Camera>    _camera;

        void executeKeyboardInput();

        void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
        void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
        ALT::InputInformation _input;

    };

}
```

Now I want to set Mouse and Key Callback from the constructor:

```
ALT::Window::Window(GLuint width, GLuint height, std::string title)
    : _width(width), _height(height)
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    _window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(_window);

    glfwSetInputMode(_window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(_window, ALT::Window::key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(_window, ALT::Window::mouse_callback);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
cannot convert ‘ALT::Window::mouse_callback’ from type ‘void (ALT::Window::)(GLFWwindow*, double, double)’ to type ‘GLFWcursorposfun {aka void (*)(GLFWwindow*, double, double)}’
     glfwSetCursorPosCallback(_window, ALT::Window::mouse_callback);
```

This error is the same for both callback functions. It is possible doing this callback function the way I am doing?

I used to do that on the main(), so I was a lot simpler.

I could also declare the callback functions outside the class, but then I could not acces the members from Window class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and pass the `this` pointer to it and then it's just casting in the outside function:

```
ALT::Window::Window(GLuint width, GLuint height, std::string title)
    : _width(width), _height(height)
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    _window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(_window);

    glfwSetWindowUserPointer(_window, reinterpret_cast<void*>(this));//<--- right here

    glfwSetInputMode(_window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    glfwSetKeyCallback(_window, ALT::key_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(_window, ALT::mouse_callback);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

}

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos){
    Window wind = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window));
    wind->mouse_callback(xpos, ypos);
}
```

Repeat for the other callbacks.

Comment: You don't even need the first `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @elmindreda it's a noop at runtime anyway and I like to make sure the semantics I want (casting back gives me the correct pointer) are there.